# How do I limit the values of a df with historical trades based on the required data needed to resample to a ohlcv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm resampling a dataframe with historical trade data to an ohlcv dataframe. Everytime I make an iteration I add a new line of trade data such that I can calculate indicators based on the new ohlcv. But my dataframe with historical trade data gets bigger every iteration and I only need the last 22 (actually 21 but the first value can be incomplete so 21 + 1) ohlcv values. And this makes my program run very slow after a while. Is there a way to delete the unneeded trade data?

Dataframe trade data:

```
                         Unnamed: 0  trade_id   price  amount  taker_side_sell
timestamp
2020-12-03 17:40:57.530       34944  12553241  89.700     3.0            False
2020-12-03 17:40:57.555       34943  12553242  89.740     1.5            False
2020-12-03 17:40:57.555       34942  12553243  89.749     9.8            False
2020-12-03 17:40:57.630       34941  12553244  89.749    11.0            False
2020-12-03 17:40:57.645       34940  12553245  89.740     1.5             True
...
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from array import *
from ta.trend import MACD

# histTrades -> df with the historical trade data

for i in array('L', range(len(histTrades.index)):
    ohlcv = pd.DataFrame()

    df = histTrades.iloc[:i]

    ohlcv = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5T')).agg({
        'price': ['first', max, min, 'last'],
        'amount': sum,
    })
    
    ohlcv.columns = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']

    if len(ohlcv) > 22 and len(openTrades) == 0:
        macdInd = MACD(ohlcv['close'], 8, 21, 5)
        macd = {'macd': macdInd.macd(), 'signal': macdInd.macd_signal(), 'hist': macdInd.macd_diff()}

        if macd['hist'][-2] < 0 and macd['hist'][-1] >= 0 and macd['macd'][-1] < 0:
            pass # Open a long trade
```

Comment: the last 22 rows is df[-22:]

Comment: Yeah yeah but I resample from a dataframe the trade data and there are for example more trades in a specific timeframe of 5min than for the timeframe before that. So I don't actually know how much trades I can remove

Comment: Guess I'm confused. Do you want reduce the historical df before resampling or reduce the sampled df after resampling? What I provided was for after resampling to just calc the indicators.

Comment: If you're looking for 22 5 minute periods just take the most recent 110 minutes of data then resample?

Comment: I would add a new trade data value to the df I do this on line 11 than I resample it to a ohlcv when I have 22 rows of data I would like to reduce the df on line 11. And no it's not just the 1min of data candles I have the a file with all the trades that are executed in a certain time interval. So yeah it are the latest 110min but that isn't a fixed number of trades. There are thousands of trades placed in those 110 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to delete the unnecessary data, and you need about 22 * 5 = 110 minutes of latest data, every once in a while you can do:

```py
histTrades = histTrades[histTrades.index > (histTrades.index.max() - pd.to_timedelta('120min')].copy() # 120 to be sure
```

Btw, `copy` creates a new DF and discards the old data (by garbage collection).